# Spring Security 3.1 and JSP taglibs not working

Tags: java, spring-security, jsp-tags

The Spring Security Docs ( http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/taglibs.html#d0e6875 ) says the following:

You can use the security taglibs to authorize access by URLs like so:

> `<sec:authorize url="/admin">`
>   This content will only be visible to users who are authorized to send requests to the "/admin" URL.
>   `</sec:authorize>`

To use this tag there must also be an instance of WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator in your application context. **If you are using the namespace, one will automatically be registered**.

OK, now...

I just upgraded from Spring Security 3.0 to 3.1

In SS 3.0, the JSP tags using URL based access worked perfectly.  When dropping in the 3.1 jars, it stopped working.

I am using the Spring Security namespace.  Therefore, I **should** have everything required to make the JSP tags work, but they don't.  Everything else about the configuration is working with my application.  The **only** thing not working is URL-based access with the JSP tags.

My config looks like the following (updated for SS 3.1).  What am I missing?

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <security:http pattern="/feed/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="digestEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="webAuthenticationManager" use-expressions="true">
        <security:http-basic/>
        <custom-filter ref="digestFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </security:http>

    <security:http name="webHttp" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="webAuthenticationManager">
        <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/autologin" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/logout" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/loginSuccess" access="" /> <!-- empty access tag.  The method checks for authenticated user -->

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
        <security:form-login login-page="/auth/login" 
                             login-processing-url="/auth/loginProcess" 
                             default-target-url="/auth/loginSuccess" 
                             authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?error=1" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/auth/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:remember-me key="remembermekey" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/auth/login"/>

    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="digestFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="digestEntryPoint" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="digestEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="realmName" value="Contacts Realm via Digest Authentication" />
        <beans:property name="key" value="acegi" />
    </beans:bean>    

    <security:authentication-manager id="webAuthenticationManager" alias="webAuthenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>     
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: It looks like when there is more than a `<http>` element on the security config only `intercept-url`s of the very first element are had into account: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?125108-sec-authorize-with-url-when-having-two-http-namespace-elements-with-different-pattern.

Comment: I mean when there is more than a `<http>` element only the `pattern` of the very first `<http>` is checked.